# How to change or transfer mailing list groups properly?

Tags: email, groups, smartgroups, mailing, best-practice

Right now - we have a smart group with all individuals tagged, in this example "Email List" and of type "Individual" as our main email list.  This has worked fine for us - as we rarely sent emails.  Now we are moving forward and investing more in email communications. We want to fork this list into two regular groups. (stop using the tag system and smart group)

- Group 1: Events and Invitations
- Group 2: Monthly E-Newsletter

The base for both groups will be our current smart group as they all indicated they want to receive updates - but I also want to make sure we honor unsubscribes. 
We are splitting the two groups up as we suspect that we will get more unsubscribes from the Monthly E-Newsletter group than from Events and Invitations (as people like coming to our events).  Also we find its easier to add people to groups via profiles, instead of tags.  (there is no add new contacts to a tag in the settings of profiles.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since folks who have already unsubscribed aren't in the smart group, I would simply search for members of the smart group, add them to group "Events and Invitations", add them to group "Monthly E-Newsletter", and delete the smart group.